# ggplotly/plotly R does not apply only integer values for each axis from ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I tried to generate a `plotly` graph in `Rshiny`, have to generate `ggplot2` then convert to `plotly`, because `plotly` itself does not provide `facet_wrap` format like `ggplot`.

It turned out that `ggplotly` automatically picks negative and decimal points that `ggplot2` objects do not have. I would like `ggplotly` generates the exact same output without decimal points and negative axis as `ggplot2` object.

Basically, for all plots with only one (0,0) point, I just want to show value 0, get rid of the non-negative numbers and keep only 0 in each axis.

Anybody can help please? Thanks a lot!

sample code:

```
lab <- tibble(
  Group = c(rep('Group 1',4),
             rep('Group 2',4),
             rep('Group 3',4),
             rep('Group 4',4)),
  Grade = c(rep(0,16)),
  Baseline = c(rep(0,16)),
  Visit = c(rep(seq(1,4),4))
)

g <- lab %>%
  group_by(Visit) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=Grade, x=Baseline)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Group), alpha=0.9) +
  scale_x_continuous("Baseline",limits = c(0,max(lab$Baseline)),breaks = unique(lab$Baseline)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Post Baseline",limits = c(0,max(lab$Grade)),breaks = unique(lab$Baseline)) +
  labs(title = "ggplot") +
  facet_wrap(~Visit, scales = "free") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())

g1 <- ggplotly(g) %>% layout(title = 'ggplotly')
```

ggplot:
[image]

ggplotly:
[image]

Comment: Try installing the dev version of plotly via devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly"). Looks like you ran in the same issue as  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1720. In the dev version this has been solved.